# Extend CDT Plugin Hide/Show line by Regex

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I would like to extend the CDT plugin for eclipse, to show/hide lines of code which are matching some regex. I don't want to "fold" via foldingStructureProviders, I really want them to be not visible while preserving line numbers. I need line numbers for later work.

Does anybody know a good extension point of the cdt c editor for that?

Example:

```
1: int main(){
2:     call_regex();
3:     return 1;
4: }
```

After activated "Hide Button":

```
1: int main(){
3:     return 1;
4: }
```

Deactivate "Hide Button":

Example:

```
1: int main(){
2:     call_regex();
3:     return 1;
4: }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up Segmented and Projected modes in Eclipse Editors.

For example, the [ProjectionViewer](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/text/source/projection/ProjectionViewer.html) which is extended by CDT's CSourceViewer.

Comment: I can probably expand my answer if you need, I'm just away from my main pc at the moment.

Comment: I am hardly be able to find some information about what that is :-/

Comment: @StefanSprenger I haven't had time to write a complete answer still, but back at my computer I was able to get the link to the correct starting point.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. How can I implement my own "CSourceViewer" do you have a small example for a plugin.xml?

Comment: CSourceViewer (org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.editor.CSourceViewer) is actually extended here org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.editor.CEditor.AdaptedSourceViewer and instantiated here org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.editor.CEditor.createSourceViewer(Composite, IVerticalRuler, int) so to replace your own source viewer, you should probably override createSourceViewer when extending CEditor. i.e. this is not handled by plugin.xml directly, but via the editor (which is declared in the plugin.xml)

Comment: If I have created a new editor, how do I choose it then as editor to be used?

Comment: If you edit the existing CEditor to add your new features (and then contribute back), I am not sure what the question means. Actually I thought you had already created an editor based on your previous posts.

Comment: I would like to extend the ceditor without changing cdt code itself. Maybe exchange the editor as extension defined in plugin.xml

Comment: Or how to declare a editor ("CustomEditor extends CEditor") in plugin.xml

Comment: Do you mean like this https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_my_own_editor%3F There is a new project wizard in Eclipse that will make you an new editor plug-in too. Choose new Plug-in in the wizard, and on one of the subsequent pages choose templates and choose the editor one.